# Sending two forms with one submit button

Tags: zend-framework

i have a little problem here. I have two forms, Login.php and Captcha.php.

My Login form contain email, password and one submit button.
And my captcha form contain the captcha.

I need valid the Login form and Captcha at same time, with submit button (login form).
But captcha form dont recognize this button in the controller.

How i can do this?

Comment: Haven't you heard? Captcha doesn't work... ;) (I hope the humor comes through)

Answer (score 0):

do this work for One form is OK,

for two forms , do submit for first form as usual and submit second form using java script (open a new link) or call url by ajax!

Answer (score 0):

Html won't allow you to submit two forms from one button.  Javascript however can do it.  [This](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml) might help you figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

first, you should post captcha and data from the same form. however, you can use this js to do this work:

```
document.forms["login-form"].onsubmit=function(){
document.forms["captcha-form"].submit();
}
```

Comment: I wanna do this inside the controller, not with Javascript. You know how i can do that?